# How can I get this hangman program into a GUI?

Tags: java, swing, class, user-interface

First, I figured I would try to write a standard hangman program without the GUI.  I was able to succeed doing that.  But I'm having trouble getting it into the GUI.  I seem to struggle with GUIs the most.

I'll show my code so far.  Maybe you guys could point me in the right direction? Or tell me if I'm on the right track?

Driver:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Hangman {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Hangman");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        HangmanPanel hmp = new HangmanPanel();

        frame.getContentPane().add(hmp);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }


}
```

Panel Class  (this one is a bit messy, because I'm trying to experiment, and I'm going through a trial and error process I guess)  My apologies if its logically off.

```
import java.awt.Panel;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class HangmanPanel extends JPanel {

private Hangman hm;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    final String[] WordList = { "ADA", "COBOL", "LOGO", "BASIC", "PROLOG",
            "UBUNTU", "UHURU" };
    String ChosenWord = WordList[(int) Math.random() * WordList.length];
    StringBuilder display = new StringBuilder(ChosenWord.length());{




    for (int i = 0; i < ChosenWord.length(); i++)
        display.append("*");

    int NumberOfTries = 0;

    System.out.print("Let's Begin \n\n");
    System.out.println("Try to guess the word in 6 tries, or you're a dead man!\n\n");

    boolean correct = false;

    while (NumberOfTries < 6 && !correct) {
        String UserGuess = input.next();
        String Letter = UserGuess.substring(0, 1);

        if (ChosenWord.indexOf(Letter) < 0) {
            System.out
                    .printf("The letter %s does not appear anywhere in the word.\n",
                            Letter);
            NumberOfTries++;
        }

        else {
            if (display.indexOf(Letter) >= 0)
                System.out
                        .printf("The letter %s has already been entered as a guess.\n",
                                Letter);

            else {
                for (int p = 0; p < ChosenWord.length(); p++)
                    if (ChosenWord.charAt(p) == Letter.charAt(0))
                        display.setCharAt(p, Letter.charAt(0));
            }
        }

        correct = display.indexOf("*") < 0;
        draw(NumberOfTries);
    }

    if (correct)
        System.out
                .println("You have guessed "
                        + ChosenWord
                        + " correct and saved yourself from the gallos. Till next time that is.\n");

    else {
        System.out
                .printf("You've had %d strikes against you. Thus you've been hung. Better luck next time.\n",
                        NumberOfTries);
    }
}

public static void draw(int num) {
    JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
    p1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
    final String[] status = { "____\n|   |\n |   \n|\n|",
            "____\n| |\n| O\n|\n|\n|", "____\n| |\n| O\n|/|\n|\n|",
            "____\n| |\n| O\n|/|\\\n|\n|", "____\n| |\n| O\n|/|\\\n|/\n|",
            "____\n| |\n| O\n|/|\\\n|/\\\n|" };
    p1.add(new JLabel("Etched Border"));

    if (num >= 0 && num < status.length) {
        System.out.println(status[num]);
    }

    else {
        System.out.println("Must be a Mistake. Out of Range.");
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swing (and most GUI's) are event driven environments.  This basically means execution of logic is normally handled by event listeners/handlers

Start by becoming familiar with how to write general user interfaces, take a look at [Creating a GUI with Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)

Using things like `while-loop`s to get user input won't work within a GUI environment, you need to build the concept of what you want to do using the available controls

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look at those tutorials. They look like they'll be easier to understand than my book.  We are studying with Lewis' Java Programming book. Sometimes I find his explanations a bit confusing.  I'm a total noob with this stuff.   And I didn't know you couldn't use while-loops in a GUI environment.   That might be why I'm struggling to much. Thanks!

Comment: I'm going through the tutorial you linked right now.  What are your thoughts on Netbeans? It seems like a really cool IDE for beginners.

Comment: I've being using NetBeans since 1999, so, yeah, I like it ;)

Comment: I'm enjoying it so far too.  It seems to write A TON of code though, almost too much.  But still, it's helpful to compare the source code to the design tab.  Very helpful actually.  I wish I knew about this sooner.  Thanks for referring me!

Comment: Be careful with the visual designer, it can tend to go over board...

Comment: I noticed that.  It writes a lot of redundant code.  In class we did a Celsius converter and it wasn't a whole lot of code.  Using this NetBeans it printed out close to 200 lines of code.

Comment: Yeah, it goes over the top.  For example, when using `GridBagLayout`, it creates new constraint objects for each component, where if I hand coded it, I might simply re-use the same one...